# Ranger - Hive service setup

Tags: mysql, hive, apache-ranger

I am trying to setup ranger service for hive authorization, but confused with the details I need to use while creating the Hive service.

I have my metastore on mysql , Ranger has it's own DB mysql.

I am confused what exactly I need to enter for below fields

```
service - can it be any name ?
Username - which user name (mysql metastore or ranger DB user?)
jdbc.url - jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

I tried with both mysql metastore & Ranger DB user with localhost jdbc & getting below error

```
org.apache.ranger.plugin.client.HadoopException: Unable to connect to Hive Thrift Server instance..
```

Gone through below doc , but it is still not clear to me what else needed

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/authorization-ranger/content/resource_service_configure_a_hive_service.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I waited for 30 ~ 60 (s), and then it worked. (docker-compose env)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@rkj

```
service - can it be any name ? <---- Can be anything
Username - which user name (mysql metastore or ranger DB user?) <--- hive service user(check with which user your hive service is running)
jdbc.url - jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

This setup is for autocompletion while giving resources(db,tables,columns).

Instead of setting manually, go to ranger service from ambari --> ranger plugin --> enable it for hive, restart hive service.

And hive will set this up in ranger